# Traceback and AttributeError That Shouldn't Be

Tags: python, pygame

I am using Python 3.8.2 and keep getting the following error.  I am completely perplexed, can someone tell me what I'm missing?

```
pygame 1.9.6
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\zbeid\vampire_pizza_directory\prepare_pizza.py", line 156, in <module>
    trap_applicator.select_tile(tile_grid[tile_y][tile_x],counters)
  File "C:\Users\zbeid\vampire_pizza_directory\prepare_pizza.py", line 104, in select_tile
    self.selected=tile.set_trap(self.selected, counters)
AttributeError: 'BackgroundTile' object has no attribute 'set_trap'
```

Script:

```
#Import libraries
import pygame
from pygame import *
from random import randint

#Initialize pygame
pygame.init()
clock=time.Clock()
WINDOW_WIDTH=1100
WINDOW_HEIGHT=600
WINDOW_RES=(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT)
WIDTH=100
HEIGHT=100
WHITE=(255, 255, 255)

SPAWN_RATE=360
FRAME_RATE=60
STARTING_BUCKS = 15
BUCK_RATE=120
STARTING_BUCK_BOOSTER=1 
REG_SPEED=2
SLOW_SPEED=1

#create window
GAME_WINDOW=display.set_mode(WINDOW_RES)
display.set_caption("Attack of the Vampire Pizzas!")

background_img=image.load('restaurant.jpg')
background_surf=Surface.convert_alpha(background_img)
BACKGROUND=transform.scale(background_surf, WINDOW_RES)


pizza_img=image.load('vampire.png')
pizza_surf=Surface.convert_alpha(pizza_img)
VAMPIRE_PIZZA=transform.scale(pizza_surf, (WIDTH, HEIGHT))

garlic_img=image.load('garlic.png')
garlic_surf=Surface.convert_alpha(garlic_img)
GARLIC=transform.scale(garlic_surf, (WIDTH, HEIGHT))

cutter_img=image.load('pizzacutter.png')
cutter_surf=Surface.convert_alpha(cutter_img)
CUTTER=transform.scale(cutter_surf, (WIDTH, HEIGHT))

pepperoni_img=image.load('pepperoni.png')
pepperoni_surf=Surface.convert_alpha(pepperoni_img)
PEPPERONI=transform.scale(pepperoni_surf, (WIDTH, HEIGHT))

class VampireSprite(sprite.Sprite):
   def __init__(self):
      super().__init__()
      self.speed=REG_SPEED
      self.lane=randint(0, 4)
      all_vampires.add(self)

      self.image=VAMPIRE_PIZZA.copy()
      y=50+self.lane*100
      self.rect=self.image.get_rect(center=(1100, y))
   def update(self, game_window):
      game_window.blit(BACKGROUND,
                       (self.rect.x, self.rect.y), self.rect)
      self.rect.x-=self.speed
      game_window.blit(self.image, (self.rect.x, self.rect.y))

class Counters(object):
   def __init__(self, pizza_bucks, buck_rate, buck_booster):
      self.loop_count = 0
      self.display_font = font.Font('pizza_font.ttf',25)
      self.pizza_bucks = pizza_bucks
      self.pizza_bucks=pizza_bucks
      self.buck_rate=buck_rate
      self.buck_booster=buck_booster
      self.bucks_rect=None

   def increment_bucks(self):
      if self.loop_count % self.buck_rate == 0:
         self.pizza_bucks += self.buck_booster
   def draw_bucks(self, game_window):
      if bool(self.bucks_rect):
         game_window.blit(BACKGROUND, (self.bucks_rect.x,
                        self.bucks_rect.y), self.bucks_rect)               
      bucks_surf=self.display_font.render(
                  str(self.pizza_bucks), True, WHITE)
      self.bucks_rect=bucks_surf.get_rect()
      self.bucks_rect.x=WINDOW_WIDTH-50
      self.bucks_rect.y=WINDOW_HEIGHT-50
      game_window.blit(bucks_surf, self.bucks_rect)
   def update(self, game_window):
      self.loop_count+=1
      self.increment_bucks()
      self.draw_bucks(game_window)
class Trap(object):
   def __init__(self, trap_kind, cost, trap_img):
      self.trap_kind=trap_kind
      self.cost=cost
      self.trap_img=trap_img
class TrapApplicator(object):
   def __init__(self):
      self.selected=None
   def select_trap(self, trap):
      if trap.cost <= counters.pizza_bucks:
         self.selected = trap
   def select_tile(self, tile, counters):
      self.selected=tile.set_trap(self.selected, counters)
class BackgroundTile(sprite.Sprite):
   def __init__(self, rect):
      super().__init__()
      self.effect=False
      self.rect=rect

all_vampires=sprite.Group()
counters = Counters(STARTING_BUCKS, BUCK_RATE,
                    STARTING_BUCK_BOOSTER)
SLOW=Trap('SLOW', 5, GARLIC)
DAMAGE=Trap('DAMAGE', 3, CUTTER)
EARN=('EARN', 7, PEPPERONI)

trap_applicator=TrapApplicator()

tile_grid=[]

tile_color= WHITE

for row in range(6):
   row_of_tiles=[]
   tile_grid.append(row_of_tiles)
    #draw.rect(BACKGROUND, tile_color, (0, HIGHT*row,
           # (WIDTH, HIGHT), 1)
   for column in range(11):
      tile_rect=Rect(WIDTH*column, HEIGHT*row,
                     WIDTH, HEIGHT)
      new_tile=BackgroundTile(tile_rect)
      row_of_tiles.append(new_tile)
      draw.rect(BACKGROUND, tile_color, (WIDTH*column,
                HEIGHT*row, WIDTH, HEIGHT), 1)

GAME_WINDOW.blit(BACKGROUND, (0,0))
#draw.circle(GAME_WINDOW, (255, 0, 0), (925, 425), 25, 0)
#draw.rect(GAME_WINDOW, (160, 82, 45), (895, 395, 100, 100), 2)
#draw.rect(GAME_WINDOW, (160, 82, 45), (895, 295, 100, 100), 0)

game_running=True

while game_running:
   for event in pygame.event.get():
      if event.type==QUIT:
         game_running=False
      elif event.type==MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
         coordinates=mouse.get_pos()

         x=coordinates[0]
         y=coordinates[1]
         tile_y=y//100
         tile_x=x//100
         #tile_grid[tile_y][tile_x].effect=True
         trap_applicator.select_tile(tile_grid[tile_y][tile_x],counters)

   if randint(1,SPAWN_RATE)==1:
      VampireSprite()
   for vampire in all_vampires:
      tile_row=tile_grid[vampire.rect.y // 100]
      vamp_left_side=vampire.rect.x // 100
      vamp_right_side=(vampire.rect.x +
                       vampire.rect.width) // 100
      if 0 <= vamp_left_side <= 10:
         left_tile=tile_row[vamp_left_side]
      else:
         left_tile=None
      if 0<= vamp_right_side <=10:
         right_tile=tile_row[vamp_left_side]
      else:
        right_tile=None
      if bool(left_tile) and left_tile.effect:
         vampire.speed=SLOW_SPEED
      if bool(right_tile) and right_tile.effect:
         if right_tile != left_tile:
            vampire.speed=SLOW_SPEED
      if vampire.rect.x <= 0:
         vampire.kill()
   for vampire in all_vampires:
      vampire.update(GAME_WINDOW)

   counters.update(GAME_WINDOW)
   display.update()
   clock.tick(FRAME_RATE)
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Where do you define `set_trap`? Did you mean `select_trap`?

Comment: Many thanks Barnard. That was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by a typo. `set_trap` should be `select_trap`:

<s>`self.selected=tile.set_trap(self.selected, counters)`</s>

```py
self.selected = tile.select_trap(self.selected, counters)
```